# in MultipleOutputs - avoid my key to be written in the files

Tags: java, hadoop

Hi im using Hadoop mapreduce and im using multipleoutput.  Below is my code

```
mos = new MultipleOutputs(context);
mos.write(key, value, propertyName.trim());
```

But it generate the multiple files with the suffix `-m-0000` How can i eliminate it ?

And also i dont wanna print my key in the file . So how can i avoid my key to be written in the files.?

Comment: 1. What else do you want other than -m-00000?
2. You don't want to write both key as well as value? So, what do you want to write basically?

Comment: @SSaikia_JtheRocker - Now check my question . I don't wanna write only the key value in my file and also i want to (-m-00000) remove this

Comment: But, mappers will run concurrently. Don't you think without -m-0000x kind of numbers, there would be overwrites?

Comment: Okay . But how can i avoid my key is being written in the file

Comment: Set the key as NullWritable.get()

Answer (score 0):

Look into using [LazyOutputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/LazyOutputFormat.html) - it won't create the default output files if nothing is written via context.write:

```
job.setOutputFormat(LazyOutputFormat.class);

// This can be any file based output format
LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
```